# Does OpenMP 5.x support classes/type bound procedures in Fortran?

Tags: oop, fortran, openmp, hpc, offloading

It looks like OpenACC supports Fortran Type Bound Procedures. So I took that code and translated the directives to OpenMP Offloading directives and that code bombs out (memory error, using nvhpc 22.x).  So does the current version of OpenMP support Fortran Type Bound Procedures?  I would provide the code, but then my question seems unpostable.

Comment: Are you particularly interested in whether OpenMP supports such features, or whether a particular compiler version implements them?

Comment: A comment I may turn into an answer after a bit more research. The OpenMP standard in section 1 says " The directives extend the C, C++ and Fortran base languages with single program multiple data (SPMD) constructs". Note the word *extends*. Thus I read this as the whole of the base language (using the OpenMP phrase) should be supported, which is currently Fortran 2018. Thus type bound procedures should be supported.

Comment: Compiler support for advanced OMP features can be spotty. For some non-offloading features I had to install GCC 12. Goodness only knows which compilers correctly handle advanced offloading features. TLDR: this question is very compiler dependent.

Comment: We (the NVHPC compiler team) don't support Type-bound procedures in device code for any of the offload models (OpenACC, OpenMP, Fortran DO CONNCURRENT, CUDA Fortran).  It's unclear why it worked in OpenACC.  It's not a standard's issue but rather lack of support for procedure pointers on the device.  Similar issue with C++ virtual functions.  We know the importance of this feature, and hopefully will be able to add this support in the future, but it will require some additional changes in the underlying CUDA toolset before we can.

Comment: FYI, Robert sent me a direct message.  He's using an OpenACC compute region within a type-bound procedure, which is fine.  To clarify, what's not supported is calling a type-bound from device code.  I'll work with him to determine the OpenMP issue.